# Can we post mythologically hypothetical questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, faq-proposed

Can we post here hypothetical questions regarding our mythological figures, for example if X was there in place of Y what would have he done, or what would have happened if instead of event A, event B happened.

Although questions like above will garner diverse views but, that's the sort of thing that would make this place bubbling with life. There are a hell lot of people with a huge bank of knowledge here so, a lengthy discourse would only enthuse the enthusiasts here.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Should this be a [FAQ](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)?

Answer (score 10):

Such questions are speculative in nature and therefore, may not be useful to the subject matter that is Hinduism. Unless very carefully worded as to elicit comparison/contrast between philosophies/schools of thought etc., such questions may not be encouraged, IMO.

Answer (score 10):

From [blog.stackoverflow.com](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/):

> Stack Exchange is about questions with objective, **factual answers**. We've been crystal clear about this for as long as I can remember, even back to the earliest, pre-beta days of Stack Overflow. It's right there in the standard Stack Exchange FAQ:
>
> #### What kind of questions should I NOT ask here?
>
> - Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion.
> - **This is not a discussion board**, this is a place for questions that can be answered!
> - Thus, questions that are not answerable -- discussions, debates, opinions -- should be closed as subjective.

However, you can always [create a new chat room on Hinduism.SE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/464/2995) and discuss off-topic subjects there. But you'll have to [invite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126100/inviting-a-user-to-chat-from-the-profile-page) a few users to [get the conversation going](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#notifications).

Comment: On chat nobody is interested.

Comment: @Vikas Most of your objective (not speculative) questions are already answered on the main site and also in chat rooms.

Comment: They *haven't* been answered yet.

Comment: @Vikas 11 out of [your 16 questions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/18497/vikas?tab=questions&sort=newest) have an answer but you haven't accepted a single answer yet.

Comment: They haven't clarified them or they don't have intention to do it.