# How to create a new chat room that's specific to Hinduism.SE?

Tags: discussion, support, chat

I see a lot of clutter at [**chat.stackexchange.com**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms) as Stack Exchange chats don't seem to be site-specific.

How do I manually create a new chat room on Hinduism.SE for discussing a subject that is usually [off-topic](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/379/2995) for the main site?

Also, should I start up a new chat room if I need attention of one of the [site moderators](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you have sufficient [privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms), you can create a new chat room at [chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new) as shown below.

If you don't have enough privilege or do not want to create a new chat room, use one of the existing Hinduism.SE's chat rooms to [chat](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat). [Here's the link to **all** Hinduism.SE chat rooms.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=hinduism.stackexchange.com)

When creating a new chat room, however, you need to **make sure you change the Related Site** (parent site) for the chat room to Hinduism.SE or else the chat will be created on Stack Overflow and other Hinduism.SE users will not be able to [locate](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=hinduism.stackexchange.com) your chat easily.

If you do forget changing the site to Hinduism.SE or you've accidentally selected a wrong site, there is no easy way to fix it. You need one of the [Stack Overflow moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) to get involved<sup>**++**</sup> to change the parent site for the chat. But this will not stop you from chatting with other users.

---

**How to create a new chat room specific to Hinduism.SE:**

[image]

---

[image]

---

<sup>**++**</sup> If you need one of the [Stack Overflow moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) to re-link your chat to Hinduism.SE, just write a comment in the chat and flag that comment for moderator attention. Explain the problem and one of the SO mods can move it under Hinduism.SE. It appears that Hinduism.SE moderators cannot fix this issue themselves without some help from SO mods. But you can always ping one of the [Hinduism.SE mods](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) and they'd be happy to communicate with an SO mod and get it fixed.

Comment: Moderators on different sites have a way of communicating with each other, so if you want you can also ping a Hinduism mod and we'd be happy to communicate with an SO mod and get it fixed.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Good to know. You can update the answer if you like as it's a wiki.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267331/260388) may also helpful

Comment: @Pandya I upvoted your FR. Hopefully, they'll implement it soon.